# Check if user is logged in on facebook without fb application

Tags: php, html, ajax, facebook

Is it possible with php to check if a visitor is connected to facebook without the use of a facebook application? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Facebook connect, because you (thankfully) can't access the facebook login info without user permissions.

More precisely, the Facebook informations are stored in a Facebook session, which Facebook only can access. That is why every part of a website which displays for exemple the people who also like a page, are in fact in an iframe.

You don't have any access to the client's FB information, unless he specifically uses Facebook connect to give your websie access to his account.